# What is the Spring boot ObjectMapper Bean scope?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot (version 2.1.5.RELEASE).

I have this class:

```java
@Component
public class DLPMessageBroker {

    @Autowired
    public DLPMessageBroker(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
     }
}
```

I'm not providing that bean anywhere else in my code. It's coming from spring.

What is the [bean scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes) for the ObjectMapper?
How can I find that information?

Comment: what's the error are you seeing? have you tried to define `objectMapper ` as a local class variable?

Comment: It's a singleton. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you means JackSon ObjectMapper, right?

in autoconfiguration where it declarates.

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
        return builder.createXmlMapper(false).build();
    }
```

by default. it is a singleton.

Comment: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration 105